# Can I write a FULL OUTER JOIN without OR IS NULL?

Tags: postgresql, join, syntax

Here's some data to play with:

```sql
CREATE TABLE a (
    a_id   int  NOT NULL,
    a_prop text NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE b (
    b_id   int  NOT NULL,
    b_prop text NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO a VALUES (1, 'blah'), (2, 'blah'), (4, 'not this one');
INSERT INTO b VALUES (1, 'blah'), (3, 'blah'), (5, 'not this one');
```

Now I'd like to write a query that returns:

[image: result]

One possibility is:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM a
FULL OUTER JOIN b ON a_id = b_id
WHERE (a_prop = 'blah' OR a_prop IS NULL)
AND (b_prop = 'blah' OR b_prop IS NULL);
```

This requires me to write `OR ... IS NULL` for every field that I have a condition on. This becomes even more verbose if some conditions are date ranges and the like.

If this were a left join:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON a_id = b_id
WHERE a_prop = 'blah'
AND (b_prop = 'blah' OR b_prop IS NULL);
```

I could move the condition to the `ON` clause to avoid this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON a_id = b_id AND b_prop = 'blah'
WHERE a_prop = 'blah';
```

Is there a way to do this with the full outer join as well?

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=54d72448652b233c122764c675d453a5)

Comment: Don't change the nature of the question after answers have been given. Next time, please start a new question instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> without `OR IS NULL`?

#### `col = 'x' OR col IS NULL`

Original:

```
SELECT *
FROM   a
FULL   JOIN b ON a_id = b_id
WHERE (a_prop = 'blah' OR a_prop IS NULL)
AND   (b_prop = 'blah' OR b_prop IS NULL);
```

Use [`col <> x IS NOT TRUE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISON-PRED-TABLE):

```
SELECT *
FROM   a
FULL   JOIN b ON a_id = b_id
WHERE  a_prop <> 'blah' IS NOT TRUE
AND    b_prop <> 'blah' IS NOT TRUE;
```

Or filter before joining:

```
SELECT *
FROM      (SELECT * FROM a WHERE a_prop = 'blah') a
FULL JOIN (SELECT * FROM b WHERE b_prop = 'blah') b ON a_id = b_id;
```

#### `col <> 'x' OR col IS NULL`

The first version of the question asked for this predicate.

Original:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
FULL OUTER JOIN b ON a_id = b_id
WHERE (a_prop <> 'not this one' OR a_prop IS NULL)
AND   (b_prop <> 'not this one' OR b_prop IS NULL);
```

Use [`col IS DISTINCT FROM 'x'`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISON-PRED-TABLE):

```
SELECT *
FROM   a
FULL   JOIN b ON a_id = b_id
WHERE  a_prop IS DISTINCT FROM 'not this one'
AND    b_prop IS DISTINCT FROM 'not this one';
```

Or filter before joining:

```
SELECT *
FROM      (SELECT * FROM a WHERE a_prop <> 'not this one') a
FULL JOIN (SELECT * FROM b WHERE b_prop <> 'not this one') b ON a_id = b_id;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=945f8ce50619f40f2a550a083f049946)* - showing all

Aside: Instead of `!=` I use `<>`, which is the standard operator in SQL. (`!=` is an accepted alias in Postgres.)

Comment: @AndreKR Filtering before the join should even be most efficient. Easiest to optimize for Postgres, especially with an index on `a_prop` and a selective predicate.

Answer (score 3):

Another option:

```
SELECT *
FROM a 
FULL JOIN b
   ON a.a_id = b.b_id
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 'blah'
    INTERSECT
    VALUES (a.a_prop), (b.b_prop)
);
```

| a_id | a_prop | b_id | b_prop |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | blah | 1 | blah |
| 2 | blah | *null* | *null* |
| *null* | *null* | 3 | blah |

[*db<>fiddle*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=54c38a17bbabb417bc05172878927a88)